# shiny R can't display a text from vector

Tags: r, shiny

How can I display value only on the browser?

Below is my code.

```
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  absolutePanel(
   textOutput("renderText1")
  )
 )
)

server <- function(input,output,session)
{
  observeEvent(input$dropdown, {
     query <-  sprintf("select ....",input$dropdown)
      cabinet_info <- dbGetQuery(con,query)
      output$renderText1 <- renderText({
        paste(cabinet_info)
      })
   })
}
```

Below are the outputs:

```
c('a','w','r','t')
```

Comment: expected output on browser : a,w,r,t

Answer (score 1):

While Geovany's answer may work, it is not a good practice to use `observeEvent` with the global assignment operator (`<<-`).

If you would like to execute a side effect (e.g. writing a file, plotting, printing), then you can use `observe` or `observeEvent`, but if you want to use a return value, use `eventReactive` instead.

```
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  absolutePanel(
    selectInput("dropdown", label = 'SelectInput', choices = c('A', 'B')),
    textOutput("renderText1")
  )
)
)

server <- function(input,output,session)
{
  cab <- eventReactive(input$dropdown, {
    query <-  sprintf("select ....",input$dropdown)
    #cabinet_info <- dbGetQuery(con,query)  #Replaced by a constant
    cabinet_info <- paste(c(input$dropdown, 'a','w','r','t'), sep=",")
  })

  output$renderText1 <- renderText({
    cab()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Call `eventReactive` from the server side just like a function: `cab()`

Answer (score 0):

This could help you

```R
runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    absolutePanel(
     actionButton("dropdown", "dropdown"),
     textOutput("renderText1")
    )
   )
  ),
  server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    cabinet_info <- NULL
    observeEvent(input$dropdown, {
        cabinet_info <<- c('a','w','r','t')
     })

    output$renderText1 <- renderText({
      input$dropdown
      paste(cabinet_info, collapse = ',')
    })
  })
))
```